# Dual monitor's never display after BIOS loads

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors, blank-screen

I am trying to set up dual monitors via Windows XP, and I am running into a very bizarre problem.  My video card is a GeForce 8800 GTS, which has dual DVI ports.  One DVI port connects to my Samsung Syncmaster LCD 2232GW via DVI cable (my primary display) while the other connects to my Sony LED TV (located in another room) via a DVI to HDMI cable.

My goal is to clone the display on both screens.  Once Windows loads, I am able to use the nVidia Control Panel to successfully do this.

The problem comes when restarting or turning on my computer.  When I do either of these, my Samsung Syncmaster never displays anything (power light just blinks on and off).  On the other hand, my Sony TV will display all the initial BIOS info you normally see when starting a computer.  When the Windows XP splash screen is supposed to appear though, my Sony TV stops showing a picture.  I have even tried to blindly log in, but it seems all functionality is disabled...

The only solution I have figured out is I need to unplug the Sony TV, restart my computer, plug in the Sony TV, then use the nVidia Control Panel to clone the screen.  As you could imagine, this is very inconvenient.

After scouring forums, I have also tried using UltraMon and Actual Multiple Monitors, but they didn't help.  If anyone has any suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it, as I have been at this for hours with no success.

Comment: Have you identified which of the two DVI ports is the *primary* port?  Seems like the port that has the Sony TV is primary, since it has the BIOS output.  Seems like you didn't mention what happens if you swap the monitor connections?  Have you tried to connect the SyncMaster with a VGA cable?

Comment: sawdust, you're a genius!  I swore I have done that in the hours I have spent trying to figure this out, but switching the DVI cables appears to have fixed the issue!

Now I just need to figure out my audio issue and I should be all set.  Thank you for your help!